# Pointers and assignment

Tags: c++

Why is

```
int *a = new int[10];
```

written as

```
int *a;
a = new int[10];
```

instead of

```
int *a;
*a = new int[10];
```

?

The way I see it, in the second block of code you're saying a, which was a pointer variable, is now an array.  In the third block of code you're saying the thing a points to is now an array.  Why does the second make more sense than the third?

Comment: Because the C declarator syntax sucks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new int[10]` returns a pointer to the first element in the array (which is of type `int*`).  It does not return a pointer to the array (which would be of type `int(*)[10]`).

`a = new int[10]` means *make `a` point to the first element of the dynamically allocated array*.  `*a` is not a pointer at all.  It is *the object pointed to by the pointer `a`* (which is of type `int`).

---

Note that if you actually had a named array object, the syntax would still be the same:

```
int x[10];
int* a = x;
```

Why?  In C++, in most cases, whenever you use an array, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element.  So here, `int* a = x` is the same as `int* a = &x[0];`.

(There are several cases where the array-to-pointer decay does not occur, most notably when the array is the operand of the `&` or `sizeof` operators; they allow you to get the address of the array and the size of the array, respectively.)

Comment: Oh, new int[10] returns a pointer!  It all makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: I think the confusion partly comes from the fact that `int *a = ...` looks like you're dereferencing `a` so that when split up it should be `int *a; *a = ...` even though it's not the same.

Comment: That's why you should write `int* a`.

Answer (score 4):

`*a = ...` means assign value to memory that I'm pointing to

`a = ...` means assign me new memory address that I should point to

Answer (score 1):

The type `int*` is a pointer to an `int`. If you apply the derefence operator to such a pointer, you get an `int` (or, more precisely, actually a reference to an `int`, i.e. a `int&`) That is, when you write

```
int* a;
*a = new int[10]; // ERROR: incompatible types `int&` and `int*`
```

you try to assign the result of `new int[10]` which is of type `int*` to an object of type `int&`. This isn't supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

> In the third block of code you're saying the thing a points to is now an array.

You're not, though.

`new` doesn't evaluate to an array, but to a *pointer* to a block of memory. That's why you're assigning to a pointer.

It's a consequence of dynamically-allocated objects not being directly reachable in the current lexical scope.

Answer (score 0):

Because this :

```
a = new int[10];
```

and this :

```
*a = new int[10];
```

are completely different things. The 2nd is the pointer dereferencing.

This:
int *a = new int[10];
and this

```
int *a;
a = new int[10];
```

are same things.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to a pointer variable, so you have to write `a`.

Would you have written

```
int* a = new int[10];
```

this would be more obvious that the type of `a` is `int*` (pointer to an `int).

Answer (score 0):

Because operator new returns the address of the object(s) it creates. `*a` is not an address, it's the `int` that `a` points at.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a pointer,

```
int *a;
```

in the memory:

```
Memory Address   Variable Identifier  Variable Value
--------------   --------------       -------------- 
0xAE934904       a                    ?
```

When you create a dynamic array, you have 10 integer numbers:

```
a = new int[10];

Memory Address   Variable Identifier  Variable Value
--------------   --------------       -------------- 
0xH3948300       -                    ?
0xH3948304       -                    ?
0xH3948308       -                    ?
0xH394830C       -                    ?
```

...
(in total,  10 integers) and value of a becomes `0xH3948300`.

```
Memory Address   Variable Identifier  Variable Value
--------------   --------------       -------------- 
0xAE934904       a                    0xH3948300
```

On the other hand, if you write `*a = new int[10];` this is `*(?)` which means go to the value that is stored at memory location `?`. *(?) is probably not a memory space where you can store memory address. If you want to assign a value to the pointer, you simply type the identifier name, `a`.