# Why is heap assignment required for array pointers? (error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction )

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I just want to know why code as below requires heap assignment in order to make it work?

(n.b. this may well be an extension to answer :  [Pointers and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956775/pointers-and-assignment))

for example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int *array;
int main(){
    array = int array[100];
}
```

creates the compiler error

```
test.cpp:7:14: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
        array = int array[100];
             ~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

but    = new int array[100]; seems to work. why ?

Comment: Both are an error.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: There are certain things that are just fixed in the syntax of the language and you need to learn. There is no *why*, other than the language was designed like that. It could very well accept that syntax, but it would not be C++ :)

Comment: I think I was trying to define an array in java like ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't require dynamic allocation. But to assign a pointer to point to an array, you need an array to point to:

```
int local_array[100];
array = local_array;
```

Your code attempts to declare an array, and then use that declaration in an expression; C++ simply doesn't let you combine declarations and expressions like that.